# ANSI SQL grouping by (Indian) financial year YTD - (last 5 years YTD)

Tags: mysql, sql

Can anyone kindly point out how to group data until today (for last 5 years) for Indian fiscal (Apr-Mar). Say for example I need to extract 'field1','field2' from table 'aaa' from 01-Apr to today date for the last 5 years. My current solution can work safe until Dec, but later will run into error

```
SELECT
         "Date",
         "Daily data",
         "ID",
         "GA%",
         "MA%"
FROM  "table" 
WHERE    month("Date")  >= 4
 AND    month("Date")  <= month(today())
 AND    date("Date")  < date(today())
```

```
Expected result format grouped by fiscal years:
FY-1 sum(daily data during the period) sum(GA) sum(MA)
FY-2 sum(daily data during the period) sum(GA) sum(MA)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
         "Date",
         "Daily data",
         "ID",
         "GA%",
         "MA%"
FROM  "table" 
WHERE    
"Date" between '2021-04-01' and '2021-11-29'
OR
"Date" between '2020-04-01' and '2020-11-29'
OR
"Date" between '2019-04-01' and '2019-11-29'
OR
"Date" between '2018-04-01' and '2018-11-29'
OR
"Date" between '2017-04-01' and '2017-11-29'
```

Comment: Sorry, but this wont give me the intended results. this is equal to select all from 01-04-2017 to current date (ytd). besides, i need to group into Indian financial years (say FY2017, FY2018 etc.) the Indian financial year runs from 01-Apr to 31-Mar.

Comment: OK - but that's not what your questions says: "I need to extract ... from 01-Apr to 29-Nov for the last 5 years". Please update your question with your precise requirements and also provide some sample data and the result you want to achieve based on that sample data - all as editable text

Comment: yes, updated. hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

*untested notepad scribble*

```
SELECT
  MIN(`Date`) AS StartDate
, MAX(`Date`) AS EndDate
, COUNT(ID) AS CountId
, SUM(`GA%`) AS `TotalGa%`
, SUM(`MA%`) AS `TotalMa%`
FROM `table` AS aaa
WHERE 
(
  (YEAR(`Date`) BETWEEN YEAR(CURRENT_DATE) - 4 AND YEAR(CURRENT_DATE) - 1) 
  OR 
  (YEAR(`Date`) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE) AND MONTH(`Date`) <= 11)
  OR
  (YEAR(`Date`) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE) - 5 AND MONTH(`Date`) > 3)
)
AND 
(
    MONTH(`Date`) NOT IN (12, 1, 2, 3)
    OR
    YEAR(`Date`) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)
) 
GROUP BY CASE WHEN MONTH(`Date`) <= 3 THEN YEAR(`Date`) - 1
              ELSE YEAR(`Date`) END
ORDER BY MIN(`Date`) DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but this wont work. It limits the data capture to <=3rd month - which in my case is Mar-21. For the current fiscal (FY2022) I have to capture data from Apr-21 to Nov-21 (YTD) and this has to be dynamic.

Comment: Then change the `<= 3` in the WHERE clause to `<= 11`.  I tried to assure full fiscal years.

Comment: sorry again, the query pulls all data from 01-apr-2016 to 30-nov-2021, whereas my requirement would necessitate excluding all parts of Dec-16/17/18/19/20, Jan-17/18/19/20, Feb-17/18/19/20, Mar-17/18/19/20.

In short - Im trying to group YTD for Indian fiscals during hte last 5 years. Indian fiscal runs from Apr-Mar

Comment: I don't really understand why you want to exclude 4 months. But I've added an extra criteria for it.

Comment: Nice, but the GROUP BY isn't ANSI SQL-92.

Comment: I realize the <sql-92> tag combined with <mysql> doesn't make much sense. However, according to ANSI SQL-92, you can't put anything but column references in the GROUP BY clause. (`<grouping column reference> ::= <column reference> [ <collate clause> ]`)

Comment: @jarlh Oh I see...  why would they add the ansi-sql-92 tag anyway?